# AngularJS - Navigation issue with $StateProvider.state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have developed a single page application. It has users, roles and permissions tabs. Home page of users tab displays all available users. Home page of Roles tab displays all available roles. Each row of role has two buttons (delete button and roledetails button). if i click on roledetails button it should navigate to roleDetails page but it is navigating to users home page. here is myapp.js file which has routing configuration.**strong text**
    can you please help me on this issue. configuration looks correct. But navigation is not as expected. Any help is appreciated..

```
angular.module('userRoles', [
        'templates-app',
        'templates-common',
        'ngBoilerplate.home',
        'ngBoilerplate.about',
        'ui.router',
        'userModule',
        'roleModule',
        'permissionModule'
    ]).config(moduleConfig);

    moduleConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function moduleConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/',
                views: {
                    'header': {
                        templateUrl: "home/header.tpl.html"
                    },
                    'footer': {
                        templateUrl: "home/footer.tpl.html"
                    },
                    'content': {
                       /* templateUrl: "user/allUsers/showAllUsers.tpl.html",
                        controller: 'ViewAllUsersController',
                        controllerAs:'viewUsers'*/
                    }
                }


            })
            .state('app.user', {
                url: '#users',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: "user/allUsers/showAllUsers.tpl.html",
                        controller: 'ViewAllUsersController',
                        controllerAs:'viewUsers'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.user.userDetails', {
                url: '#users/:id',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: "user/userDetails/userDetails.tpl.html",
                        controller: 'userDetailController',
                        controllerAs:'userDetailCntrl'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.user.deleteUser', {
                url: '#users/:id',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: "user/deleteUser/deleteUser.tpl.html",
                        controller: 'deleteUserController',
                        controllerAs:'deleteUser'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.role', {
                url: '#roles',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: "role/allRoles/showAllRoles.tpl.html",
                        controller: 'viewAllRolesController',
                        controllerAs:'viewRoles'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.role.roleDetail', {
                url: '#roleDetails/:roleId',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: "role/roleDetails/roleDetails.tpl.html",
                        controller: 'roleDetailController',
                        controllerAs:'roleDetails'

                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.role.deleteRole', {
                url: '#rolesDelete/:roleId',
                controller: 'deleteRoleController',
                controllerAs:'deleteRole',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: "role/allRoles/showAllRoles.tpl.html"
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.permission', {
                url: '#permissions',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: "permission/allPermissions/showAllPermissions.tpl.html",
                        controller: 'viewAllPermissionsController',
                        controllerAs:'viewPermissions'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.permission.deletePermission', {
                url: '#permissions/:name',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: "permission/deletePermission/deletePermission.tpl.html",
                        controller: 'deletePermissionController',
                        controllerAs:'deletePermissions'
                    }
                }
            })
            ;



       /* $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');*/
    }

displayRoles.tpl.html ::

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-11">
        <h3></h3>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th ng-click="viewRoles.sortBy='roleId'; viewRoles.sortOrder = !viewRoles.sortOrder;">Role ID</th>
                <th ng-click="viewRoles.sortBy='roleName'; viewRoles.sortOrder = !viewRoles.sortOrder;">Role Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="role in viewRoles.roleList | filter:viewRoles.searchTxt | orderBy:viewRoles.sortBy:viewRoles.sortOrder">
                <td><a ui-sref="app.role.roleDetail({roleId: role.roleId()})"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span></a>
                </td>
                 <td><a ui-sref="app.role.deleteRole({roleId: role.roleId()})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                 </td>
                <td>{{role.roleId()}}</td>
                <td>{{role.roleName()}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

1. List item

Comment: How exactly is the "navigation not as expected"?  Can you more clearly describe what you are expecting to happen, and what is actually happening, so that we can better understand what the question/issue is?

Comment: displayRoles.tpl.html file has an action button which takes to role details page. If i click on this action button, application should navigate to role details page instead it is navigating to users page which is home page of the application. So expected behavior is navigating to role details page.

Comment: ui-router navigates to the base path of the app when an error is encountered. This behavior means there is probably a problem in your roleDetail button's method. If you change the roleDetail button to only have ui-sref="app.role.roleDetail" does it then route to the state correctly?